# When was the phrase "lumped thermal capacitance" first coined?

Tags: heat-transfer, engineering-history

As per the title, when was the phrase "lumped thermal capacitance" to describe a particular way of analysing multi-component heat transfer and energy storage systems first coined, please?  I can find a couple of publications using the phrase in the early 1950s, but they're written as if the authors expected readers already to be familiar with the phrase.

Comment: Do a search in the journals and papers.

Comment: @SolarMike  I did, that's how I found those publications from the early 1950s.

Comment: Then, if as you say the phrase is already common, there must be earlier papers for you to find.

Comment: [HSM Stack Exchange](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Imagine tea, and lumps of sugar dissolving with the help of heat.  Spread that story far and wide until everyone either accepts it, or someone corrects you...

Comment: I think Bickley (1941, _Lond. Edinb. Dublin Philos. Mag. J. Sci._ **32**(210):50-66, doi:10.1080/14786444108521297) might be it, and am pondering whether I need to be sure strongly enough to pay the publisher's exorbitant fee for full-text access to that paper.

Answer (score 1):

Putting in a self-answer although I'm not entirely satisfied with it:

The use of the word "lumped" to describe thermal systems in this way was introduced by Bickley (1941, *Lond. Edinb. Dublin Philos. Mag. J. Sci.* **7th series: 32**(210):50-66, doi:10.1080/14786444108521297).  There are some earlier uses for *electrical* systems.

(Why am I not entirely satisfied?  Firstly, Bickley never uses the complete phrase "lumped thermal capacitance"; secondly, although Bickley's model includes both "resistances" (heat transfer) and "capacitances" (energy storage), he only ever lumps one of the resistances, not the capacitances.)